# Separating multiple values in Excel so that SharePoint List will recognise the different values

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I am trying to import content from an Excel spreadsheet into a Sharepoint List. One of the fields in the List is the 'type of work' the applicant seeks, which is a 'choice' field that permits multiple selections (see attached image)

[image]

To create a similar variable from the existing Excel spreadsheet, I have had to draw from multiple columns, as we were not storing the information in one column. The result in column H (in Excel) is a string with the different 'types of work' (as named in the List) (see attached).

[image]

When I try to import the data from Excel to the List by going to 'Edit in Grid View' (in SharePoint List) and then copying and pasting the data from Excel to List all the content is correctly copied across except where there is more than one 'type of work' option in the cell copied from Excel (see below).

[image]

The error message associated with the fields in red states that '"marking work Course Coord" are not a valid value for this field'.

I have tried adding commas, semi-colons and ;# between the multiple values but the same error message appears.

Is there a way to separate multiple values in Excel so that SharePoint List will recognise the values as multiple values from those available?

Thank you in advance for any help or advice you might have.

Comment: (To assist troubleshooting..) How to re-create the case u r having? Any samples / shared files / specific guide to refer to?

Comment: I found exactly what I was looking for at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JSehvqonyU.

Answer (score 2):

You can Import an Excel Column with Multiple Values into a Multi Choice Field with Power Automate. I took a simple screenshot of the flow steps in the video in case the link doesn't work.

Reference：https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JSehvqonyU

[image]
[image]
[image]